# Add Regex Matches as new columns to the csv file [Batch Scripting]

Tags: regex, csv, batch-file, command-line

I have a .csv file that I need to add regex matches in each line as new columns after the original columns, here is a part of the .csv file:

```
"Event";"User";"Description"   
"stock_change";"usertest1@gmail.com";"Change Product Teddy-Bear (Shop ID: AR832H0823)"
"stock_update";"usertest2@gmail.com";"Update Product 30142_Pen (Shop ID: GI8759)"
```

Here is the two Regex Patterns I want to add their extracted results from each row as new columns (one column for each)

```
(?<=Product\s)\w.*?(?=\s*\(Shop)

(?<=Shop ID:\s)\w.*?(?=\))
```

The Result on the data should be Like this (Header Row is not important):

```
"stock_change";"usertest1@gmail.com";"Change Product Teddy-Bear (Shop ID: AR832H0823)";"Teddy-Bear";"AR832H0823"  
"stock_update";"usertest2@gmail.com";"Update Product 30142_Pen (Shop ID: GI8759)";"30142_Pen";"GI8759"
```

Sorry I'm very basic in Batch Scripting, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows batch does not have a native regex find/replace utility. The only regex utility is FINDSTR, and that is extremely limited and non-standard, and it can only print out entire lines that match the search - it cannot print out just the matching portion.

You could use PowerShell.

But I would use [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - a purely script based utility (hybrid JScript/batch) that works on any Windows machine from XP onward. It uses ECMA regular expressions, so no look-behind, but it has plenty of power to do the task.

```
jrepl "Product\s(\S+?)\s*\(Shop ID:\s(.*?)\)\q$" "$&;\q$1\q;\q$2\q" /a /x /f test.csv /o -
```

The `/a` switch discards unchanged lines, which effectively removes the header line. The `/o -` option overwrites the original file with the output. The `/x` switch enables extended escape sequences, thus enabling `\q` for `"`.

Use `call jrepl` if you put the command in a batch script.

Full documentation is available from the command line via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged output.

Comment: Thanks dbenham, I was surprised when I saw that JREPL tool was developed by you :) , wondering if I can use the same tool for this issue too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828741/search-replace-text-within-csv-fields-using-batch-scripting

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this GNU sed command:

```
sed -r 's/^.*Product (.+) \(Shop ID: (.+)\)"$/&;\"\1\";\"\2\"/g' shop.csv
```

- it captures the parts between `Product`, `(Shop ID:` and `)"` into `\1` and `\2`
- the replacement uses `&` (the whole line) and appends a string made up of `\1` and `\2`

Comment: Worth noting that this this an external program that he's going to have to download.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be solved in a very simple way without a regex with this Batch file:

```
@echo off

(for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims=;" %%a in (input.csv) do (
   for /F "tokens=3,6 delims=() " %%d in (%%c) do (
      echo %%a;%%b;%%c;"%%d";"%%e"
   )
)) > output.txt
move /Y output.csv input.csv
```

Result:

```
"stock_change";"usertest1@gmail.com";"Change Product Teddy-Bear (Shop ID: AR832H0823)";"Teddy-Bear";"AR832H0823"
"stock_update";"usertest2@gmail.com";"Update Product 30142_Pen (Shop ID: GI8759)";"30142_Pen";"GI8759"
```

However, if there are lines that have not the format of the example data (that could be correctly processed with a regex, but not with this code), then an adjustment in this code may be required. Note that depending on the differences in the data, the problem *may* not be solved via a pure Batch file.