# Search & Replace Text within CSV fields using Batch Scripting

Tags: csv, batch-file, command-line

I have a semicolon ";" delimited CSV file with "" as Text Quantifier, however there are fields which have ";" or "" which break the lines; How can I use a batch script to replace such values in each field each row, but keep the Field delimiter (;) and Text Quantifier ("") the same? (Example Replace ";" in each field with "|" and Double-Quotes Single-Quotes)

Note: We can Rely on the **";"** part between each two fields (Start and End of each field has the double-quotes, possible to use it as imaginary delimiter in the solution)

Here as an example of my csv rows with corrupted Fields:

```
"Event";"User";"Description"   
"stock_change";"usertest1@gmail.com";"Change Product Teddy;Bear (Shop ID: "AR832H0823")"
"stock_update;change";"usertest2@gmail.com";"Update Product "30142_Pen" (Shop ID: GI8759)"
```

Comment: That's not a question but a task request; please share what you have tried so far; remember that SO is not a free code writing service...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35828741.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
FOR /L %%f IN (1,1,3) DO SET "field%%f="
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR %%b IN (%%a) DO CALL :process %%b
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:process
IF NOT DEFINED field1 SET "field1=%~1"&GOTO :EOF 
IF NOT DEFINED field2 SET "field2=%~1"&GOTO :EOF 
SET "field3=%~1"
:repcwp
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%f IN ("%field3%") DO (
 SET "field3=%%g"
 IF DEFINED field3 (SET "field3=%%f''%%g"&GOTO repcwp) ELSE (SET "field3=%%~f")
)
set "field1=%field1:;=|%"
set "field1=%field1:"='%"
set "field2=%field2:;=|%"
set "field2=%field2:"='%"
set "field3=%field3:;=|%"
set "field3=%field3:"='%"
ECHO "%field1:''=:%";"%field2:''=:%";"%field3:''=:%"
FOR /L %%f IN (1,1,3) DO SET "field%%f="
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q35828741.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Process each line of the file, presuming it is well-constructed.

Use a simple `for` loop to deliver the three fields to the procedure :process. The lines are each of the form "data1"*separator*"data2"*separator*"data3"

Within `:process`, accumulate the data to `field1..3`

Since the common substring-replace mechanism uses `:` to separate the "to" and "from" strings, replace each `:` with a distinct string `''`. This is only done for `field3` since it appears from the sample data that it is the only field that may contain colons. If colons may appear in the other fields, it's simply a matter of following the bouncing ball.

Having replaced all the colons, replace the semicolons and rabbit's-ears as required, then in the `echo` which outputs the data to the destination file, replace any `''` with colon.

This makes a number of assumptions, including that the data contains no `%` or other awkward characters and that there are no instances of `::` in the data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want to convert `teddy;bear` to `teddy|bear`, but... OK.

As requested in comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35822437/1012053, you can use the `/T` option of my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) to perform the following find/replace (earlier find/replace take precedence):

- `"` at beginning of line, or `";"` anywhere, or `"` at end of line ==> leave as us
- `"` any place else ==> convert to `'`
- `;` any place else ==> convert to `|`

```
jrepl "^\q|\q;\q|\q$ \q ;" "$& ' |" /x /t " " /f test.csv /o -
```